# Canvas Group component in child canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas

I am using a child canvas inside a parent canvas in my Unity 2D mobile game. I am searching whether there is any performance impact if I add a `Canvas Group` component to the child canvas to control the alpha of it.

[image: Hierarchy]

Comment: https://unity3d.com/how-to/unity-ui-optimization-tips section `Avoid Layout Groups where possible`

Comment: @derHugo I think by `Layout Groups` they mean Horizontal/ Vertical/ Grid Layout groups.